# Is that possible to cache django flatpages?

Tags: django, django-flatpages

Is that possible to cache django flatpages ?
When I look at the code it seems it is not done...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just [cache your site as normal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache) and make sure that `FetchFromCacheMiddleware` is before `FlatpageFallbackMiddleware`. In this case, caching doesn't need to be done on the application level.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do this is **just** cache flatpage views (not cache all views!)

I recommend something like this:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages import views
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^pages/(?P<url>.*)$', cache_page(60 * 60)(views.flatpage), name='django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage'),
    # other routes here ...
    ]
```